# haProxy: How to retain haproxy IP in URL

Tags: haproxy

I have setup haproxy  -X with two backend server Y and Z

My problem is when I call X (haproxy) it redirects correctly to Y or Z but URL is also changed (Containing Y or Z IP), So now I am talking directly to WebServer instead of haProxy Server.

is there a way to retain haProxy IP in requests ?

haproxy.cfg

```
    global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 2000
  user haproxy
  group haproxy

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend LB
   bind *:80
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   option   httplog
   default_backend LB

backend LB
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats hide-version
   stats uri /stats
   stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
   stats auth haproxy:redhat        # Credentials for HAProxy Statistic report page.
   balance roundrobin           # Load balancing will work in round-robin process.
   option httpchk
   option  httpclose
   option forwardfor
   option   httplog
   cookie LB insert
   server web1-srv 10.164.29.225:80 cookie web1-srv check       # backend server.
   server web2-srv 10.164.27.31:80 cookie web2-srv check        # backend server.
```

Comment: Observe the response headers, and you should find that the problematic behavior comes from the backend servers -- not HAProxy -- because in their responses, at some point, they are generating a `30X` redirect with a `Location` header containing the IP/hostname of the individual back-end.  HAProxy is not "redirecting" in your configurarion shown here -- it is only *forwarding* -- so there is no URL change being triggered by HAProxy.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks, I checked the response Headers and it does have Location header

Comment: @AbhinavGarg may be late comment, Hoping you have resolved the issue by changing the `Location` header content. May be you could write the answer with description what all the changes and valuations you have done for fixing this issue.